# SQL query for getting data in two fields from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table [Tbl1] containing two fields.

ID as int And
TextValue as nvarchar(max)

Suppose there are 7 records. I need a resultset that has two columns Text1 and Text2.
The Text1 should have first 4 records and Text2 should have remaining 3 records.

### [Tbl1]

### ID   |      TextValue

### 1.   |      Apple

### 2.   |      Mango

### 3.   |      Orange

### 4.   |      Pineapple

### 5.   |      Banana

### 6.   |      Grapes

### 7.   |      Sapota

Now, the result-set should have

---

### Text1     |        Text2

### Apple     |        Banana

### Mango     |        Grapes

### Orange     |        Sapota

### Pineapple   |

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What is your actual use case for this?

Comment: I am using RDBMS for ms sql server.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by that? I've a hunch that you want PIVOT functionality..not sure though.

Comment: I want the result set to render in a ssrs report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder how this can be useful, but I think you could try the following:

```
SELECT      t1.TextValue AS Text1,
            t2.TextValue AS Text2
FROM        tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN   tbl1 t2 ON ((t2.id - 4) = t1.id)
WHERE       t1.id <= 4;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (id int, textvalue varchar(15));

INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(1, 'Apple');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(2, 'Mango');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(3, 'Orange');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(4, 'Pineapple');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(5, 'Banana');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(6, 'Grapes');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(7, 'Sapota');
```

Result:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Text1     | Text2  |
+-----------+--------+
| Apple     | Banana |
| Mango     | Grapes |
| Orange    | Sapota |
| Pineapple | NULL   |
+-----------+--------+
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As @[AlexCuse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794/alexcuse) suggested in a comment below, you could also use a variable to get the row count of the table, in order to have a query that works for any number of rows:

```
DECLARE @x float;

SET @x = ROUND((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1) / 2.0, 0);

SELECT      t1.TextValue AS Text1,
            t2.TextValue AS Text2
FROM        tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN   tbl1 t2 ON ((t2.id - @x) = t1.id)
WHERE       t1.id <= @x;
```

Comment: I also fail to see the usefulness, but you may want to get the total count first, and make it where t1.id <= Ceiling( (@cnt * 1.00) / 2), that way it is more flexible ;)

Comment: Its right answer but, Can I get same result without being dependent on ID.

Comment: Still the answer is dependent on ID. If I replace the ID column with date field and there is no any order in dates. Now the text data after a specific date should come in 1st column and remaining in 2nd column. I am not sure, is it possible to get same result-set without using IDs

Comment: @AmitT: Yes, I think what you require can be done with Pivots, as was suggested in the comments to your question. I recommend posting another question on this, maybe giving a couple of realistic examples which you like to group in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT t.textvalue AS text1,
       (SELECT x.textvalue
          FROM TBL x
         WHERE x.id = t.id + 4) AS text2
  FROM TBL t
 WHERE t.id <= 4
```